# SQL fill rows with value from one row in a view

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012, window-functions

So to simply things say i am creating a view that retrieves survey data from 4 different tables, I don't have any control over the structure of these tables as they are from a 3rd party.

```
SELECT v.SurveyID, v.VoterID, v.VoteDate, a.QuestionId, a.AnswerId,
 (CASE WHEN a.questionid IN ('8', '509', '514', '516', '518', '519', '577', '723','724', '725', '726', '727', '730')
THEN Fn_surveyconvertanswer(a.answerid, '') ELSE (CASE WHEN a.questionid IN ('758','124') AND a.answerid IN ('2631', '647') THEN CONVERT(INT, CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), va.answertext)) ELSE '' END) 
END)    AS StoreID
FROM Answer a
LEFT JOIN VoterAnswers AS va ON a.AnswerId = va.AnswerID 
LEFT JOIN Voter v AS v ON va.VoterID = v.VoterID
LEFT JOIN Question q AS q ON a.QuestionId = q.QuestionId
```

now say i also need a column with StoreID which can only found when say QuestionID is in ('3','43','55') then each answerID = a certain store (there is actually another table to link answerID to storeID but that is irrelevant to the question.) If i use a case statement to find it, it would only show up for the one row, this means that the views table would look like

```
+----------+---------+----------+------------+----------+---------+
| SurveyID | VoterID | VoteDate | QuestionId | AnswerID | StoreID |
+----------+---------+----------+------------+----------+---------+
|        5 |       1 | 9/4/2014 |          1 |       52 |       0 |
|        5 |       1 | 9/4/2014 |          2 |       43 |       0 |
|        5 |       1 | 9/4/2014 |          3 |       78 |      97 |
|        5 |       1 | 9/4/2014 |          4 |       87 |       0 |
|        5 |       1 | 9/4/2014 |          5 |       98 |       0 |
+----------+---------+----------+------------+----------+---------+
```

how would i get the storeID 97 to be in all the rows since all that survey data is for that store?

EX.

```
+----------+---------+----------+------------+----------+---------+
| SurveyID | VoterID | VoteDate | QuestionId | AnswerID | StoreID |
+----------+---------+----------+------------+----------+---------+
|        5 |       1 | 9/4/2014 |          1 |       52 |      97 |
|        5 |       1 | 9/4/2014 |          2 |       43 |      97 |
|        5 |       1 | 9/4/2014 |          3 |       78 |      97 |
|        5 |       1 | 9/4/2014 |          4 |       87 |      97 |
|        5 |       1 | 9/4/2014 |          5 |       98 |      97 |
+----------+---------+----------+------------+----------+---------+
```

I had it working by doing left joins on basically the same query above on VoterID (as this is also unique for each survey taken) and doing some grouping but now there are multiple fields like the StoreID above gathered in the same manner. It is starting to become a mess and is actually causing some odd grouping errors when saved as a view. (oddly works fine as a stand alone query) I was wondering if there was a better more effecent way to just populate the rest of the rows with the storeID

I have used temp tables for stuff like this in the past with great results but can't use them in a view.

Comment: How about some ddl and sample data? sqlfiddle.com would be a great place to start.

Comment: Populate storeID with a subquery.

Comment: Well i was in the middle of doing a subquery for the StoreID when i realized there had to be better way, because there are other fields like it so i would end up doing about 5 subqueries for every single row.

Comment: I think the part you're saying is irrelevant is the most important part for developing an alternate solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add CTE queries with WITH statement and join them to you view instead of using in-line sub-queries.

Even better you should insert missing rows that will allow you to join all records to the corresponding shop.

One more alternative is to use MAX() if you set it to 0 where it is missing:

```
MAX(<ShopId case clause>) OVER() as ShopId
```

Comment: The storeID is calculated from a case statment, i mentioned it above.

Comment: I was looking into the CTE queries and i think i could figure that out but could you elaborate on what you mean by inserting missing rows?

Comment: as far as providing the full working SQL its a mess right now that's why i am recreating it, I will try to get just a working sample

Comment: Only one line has the question that corresponds to the storeid

Comment: Which means that all other lines are missing as far as I can understand it. I have updated the answer with MAX() option. May be you will need MAX() OVER() not sure.

Comment: I added the case statement that is being used to get storeID

Comment: The function that it calls is basically a small table lookup...not sure why it was written that way, btw i didn't write any of that mess.

Comment: Try MAX(<>) OVER() and see where it gets you.

Comment: adding OVER() worked, although i have to admit i don't quite understand why, the only time i have used OVER() was to display a row number. I read http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189461.aspx but it didn't help explain much. Thank you btw

Comment: OVER makes it look within certain window of other rows, if OVER() does not have partition defined, query runs through ALL rows. so `MAX() OVER()` gets you max value in entire column.

Comment: ahh i see i may have to actually define a partition in the end then so it does not just return the max storeID but the max storeID for that particular survey